# this keyword differs in Runtime and compile time

Tags: java, object, inheritance, memory

1.Can Some one illustrate how it works? Why it prints 1 instead of 2?

2.From the Oracle Official Java tutorial, the definition of `this`: Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using this.

```
    // Base Class
    class A { 

        public int m = 1;


        public void view(){
            // Print variable m
            System.out.println(this.m);

            //print the current class name
            System.out.println(this.getClass());
        }

    }

    // Subclass extends Base Class
    public class B extends A{

        // Define another variable m
        public int m = 2;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            B b = new B();
            b.view();
        }

    }
```

Below is the debug of the view(){}:

[image]

My Question is:
You can see the current object is B, when we use`this`, it represents the `B`, **m = 1 in base class A, m = 2 in derived class B,** then use the `this.m`, it should print 2, isn't it?

Comment: There exists **no** property overriding in java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override a property in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163255/override-a-property-in-java)

Comment: Methods can be overridden, not fields. `B.m` is a different field from `A.m`.

Comment: When the compiler compiles the code for class `A`, it interprets the expression `this.m` to mean the `m` that class `A` defines.  It neither knows nor cares that you're going to introduce another class with a different `m`.

Comment: The comments provide the answer, and that's why high-grade IDE's for java typically have a feature that issues warnings against name shadowing.

Comment: @Lino Hi mate, I know there is no fields overriding in java, what I'm asking is that: when `B` object runs this line of code: `System.out.println(this.m);`, `this` means `B`, right ? (because `this`represents the current object), then because of the reason that B has a field `m = 2`, why the answer is not 2?

Comment: @khelwood Hi mate, I know there is no fields overriding in java, what I'm asking is that: when `B` object runs this line of code: `System.out.println(this.m);`, `this` means `B`, right ? (because thisrepresents the current object), then because of the reason that B has a field `m = 2` why the answer is not 2?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem But, `this` do represents the current object which is `B`, when runs`this.m`, it means `B.m`, why just  simply because `this.m` is in `class A`, so the answer is 1 ?

Comment: When the compiler compiles the method `view`, it knows that `this` will be an instance of `A`, and it resolves `this.m` as the `m` field declared in `A`, which is the only thing it possibly _could_ resolve it to. The fact that your object at run-time has another field also called `m` does not affect that.

Comment: @khelwood, thats not right, `this` is an instance of `B`, just copy the code above and run it, this line of code: `this.getClass()` prints `Class B`

Comment: It's _runtime_ type is `B`. But the _compiler_ regards it as type `A`, because it's `this` inside a method in class `A`, and that's how `this` works.

Comment: An object  of class `B` has two fields called `m`.  Which one `this.m` refers to depends on which class it's written in, because the choice is made at compile time, not run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are not polymorphic in Java; they do not override one another.